# Why does Stack Overflow use a backtracking regex implementation?

Tags: support, architecture

The [postmortem for the recent Stack Overflow outage](http://stackstatus.net/post/147710624694/outage-postmortem-july-20-2016) implicates a backtracking implementation of regular expression matching in the outage.

O(N) implementations of regex matching that don't require backtracking exist -- see Russ Cox's paper [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) for more background. The [RE2 library](https://github.com/google/re2) for example is open source, and it seems like it should be possible to use from the Stack Overflow stack, although it is written in C++.

Are there technical reasons why Stack Overflow uses a backtracking regex library, or is it simply a case of using the simplest thing that worked since it never was a problem before? I'm surprised that switching to a different regex implementation (or even a custom non-regex DFA sanitizer) isn't one of the follow-up actions listed in the postmortem.

Comment: Wild guess: Stack Overflow is built on .NET. .NET's regex implementation is backtracking. You generally don't start replacing major components of your standard library just for the hell of it; you wait for necessity.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/

Comment: @HansPassant - Heh, nice find. Very telling that it would contain Atwood remarking that "When I throw a regex together, I never worry about performance". Whoops! :)

Comment: @Shog9: Sure, that would make sense initially. But now that the necessity (or, at very least, the danger) *has* been demonstrated, why not consider an alternative that is guaranteed not to have this behavior? My real question is: why isn't "switch to a different regex engine" one of the action items that came out of the postmortem?

Comment: @Shog9 Looks like it supports [nonbacktracking subexpressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4(v=vs.110).aspx#controlling_backtracking)

Comment: @Shog9 .NET doesn't have possessive quantifiers, but you could have used an atomic group to prevent backtracking. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5537513/5743988)

Comment: There's no need to replace the entire regex engine when you can just write a regex that doesn't cause catastrophic backtracking. I'm not sure about .NET, but at least in Perl, the problem can be solved by splitting the regex into two separate ones, e.g. `^\s+|\s+$` becomes `^\s+` and `\s+$`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: My team's perspective (which admittedly is not everyone's) is that if there's a way to use an API incorrectly, people will end up using it incorrectly. Even the best developers make mistakes. I'm a big fan of flagging suspect uses of APIs using static analysis, but sometimes it's better to just switch to a different API that is guaranteed to be used correctly.

Comment: To prevent catastrophic backtracking in .NET 4.5 you can specify a Timeout property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=VS.110).aspx#Timeouts

Comment: *direct cause was a malformed post that caused one of our regular expressions to consume high CPU on our web servers* I'd like to see how you guys diagnosed it back to a Post with the RegEx `^[\s\u200c]+|[\s\u200c]+$`  > **Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”
Now they have two problems.**

Comment: @JeremyThompson especially interested in how they did it in 10 minutes.

Comment: Are there privacy reasons why the malformed post isn't identified?

Comment: They kind of did identify it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484433/join-tiles-in-corona-sdk-into-one-word-for-a-breakout-game-grid

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: In .NET, the problem can be resolved by splitting the regex, but we will use RightToLeft mode when trimming spaces from the end. I don't know for sure, but I doubt .NET has the same optimization as Perl in such case.

Comment: .NET should use a non-backtracking engine for expressions that do not require that. .NET regex performance is not so great.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Quick answer: Memory dump got us to the Regex and front page.  Front page is an algorithm applied to the newest 3000 posts. While one person fixed the regex, another ran the regex against those to last 3000 since they don't change when no one can post. Found the post that took the longest to run. Problem found and fixed.

Comment: @Zypher, cool I know exactly what you mean: https://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2009/07/04/diagnosing-stack-overflow-faults-in-asp-net-production-environments/

Comment: So is `regex` library.

Comment: OTOH, if I build this using defensive programming, I'd leave it to UI to string whitespace, and then server only needs to validate 2 bytes -- first and last; i.e. no kleene stars. Of course I'd code it in a way that SEGVs on 0-len input :)